# Mobile application with the same intent of a bulk sms

Tags: mobile-application

Please I have an idea to build a mobile application for my church, although I have started building it. But I need an advice as to how to go about certain things. I dont want to work amidst.

The main idea

1. The users of the app will receive daily bible verses and encouraging words from the administrator.
2. Events and announcement for church services wld be sent to all users of the application.

Please what are the things I shld read about if I want to build such an application.  I would be grateful if someone could give me a foreknowledge of what I am doing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Push notifications instead of SMS, will be much cheaper. Rather than building separate apps for iOS and Android consider using a framework that generates both.

Comment: Please does the push notifications come with a charge? And Please I didnt understand your second statement.

Comment: Push notifications are free, that's why they will be better than SMSes. When you're building mobile apps you can build native apps (using Objective-C or Swift for iPhone, Java for Android) or you can use a framework which generates code for both. Check out Ionic http://ionicframework.com/ and PhoneGap http://phonegap.com/

Comment: Oh ok, thats good...but please I want to find out if the framework that generates both codes are robust. Please do they have some disadvantages as compared to the native apps?